# How to Override Controller or it's method in NopCommerce Plugin?

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I am creating a plugin for price range filter. all design parts are done.

Now i want to Override  ActionResult method Category of CatalogController.

I did lots of R&D, all of them are creating new methods so they don't need to Override existing one.

I am Stucked Here from last 10 hours, can anyone please help me?

Comment: you can do that using route and give it's priority

Comment: Add your plugin method and route file, will help you.

Comment: @Div: but i didn't get references of old methods attributes in my plugin method? how to resolve that?

Comment: *old methods attributes* what do you mean, default nopComemrce method?

Comment: yes. for example my Default method gets lots of stuff from other methods of that controller. and if i try to add all that in my plugin controller they give me error of references.

Comment: @Div : ok, trying thanks!

Comment: in sort i can override any actionresult/Method of default controller and that's what i want to here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive your plugin controller from existing CatalogController to avoid code duplication, and then you have to create a new route in your plugin RouteProvider class (with appropriate priority) to replace existing route and use your own action method.